# Display of numbers varies when creating a JSON object

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, floating-point

I have the following function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aggregate_view(ticker text, from_time timestamp)
RETURNS TABLE (data text)
LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT
    json_build_object(
        'candles',
        (SELECT json_agg(array [EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_bucket), "open", high, low, "close", volume :: BIGINT]) AS json_array_of_arrays
        FROM exchange.candles_d1
        WHERE exchange.candles_d1.ticker = $1 AND candles_d1.ts_bucket >= $2 AND candles_d1.ts_bucket < $2 + INTERVAL '1 hour'),

        'kvwap',
        (SELECT json_agg(array [EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_bucket), m1, m5, m15, m30, h1, h2, h4, d1, low, vwap, high]) AS json_array_of_arrays
        FROM exchange.kvwap_d1
        WHERE exchange.kvwap_d1.ticker = $1 AND kvwap_d1.ts_bucket >= $2 AND kvwap_d1.ts_bucket < $2 + INTERVAL '1 hour'),

        'zones',
        (SELECT json_agg(array[EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_confirmation)::BIGINT, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts_end)::BIGINT, confirmations, CAST(is_continuation AS INT)])
        AS json_array_of_array
        FROM analysis.zones
        WHERE analysis.zones.ticker = $1 AND "interval" = 'D1' AND ts_confirmation >= $2 AND ts_confirmation < $2+ INTERVAL '1 hour')
    )
$func$;
```

The timestamps are stored as (time - EPOCH) but in the output json,  formatting differs from one table to the next. The first value in each chunk is the timestamp:

```
 {
   "candles":[
      [
         1577836800,
         7189.43,
         7260.43,
         7170.15,
         7197.57,
         409678761
      ]
   ],
   "kvwap":[
      [
         1.5778368e+09,
         7213.8125,
         7213.5947,
         7212.4907,
         7210.914,
         7209.1133,
         7207.789,
         7207.2,
         7206.961,
         7170.15,
         7213.8574,
         7260.43
      ]
   ],
   "zones":null
}
```

Notice how one timestamp is written as ***1577836800***, but the other one as ***1.5778368e+09***, which is the same number.

Why is that? And how to prevent the number from being displayed in scientific notation?

Comment: It should be obvious to disclose your version of Postgres with any such question. Also please strip all the noise from the question that is unrelated to the question of E notation versus plain  notation. Reduce your reproducible example to two arrays of two elements each and disclose input data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Postgres array stores elements of *one* data type. The [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) finds the best common denominator (if possible) if input types vary.

Most likely, one of the columns (`m1, m5, m15, m30, h1, h2, h4, d1, low, vwap, high`)  in the table `exchange.kvwap_d1` has data type **`real`** (`float4`). (And none is `float8`.) This forces the data type of the constructed array to be `real[]`. The representation of `1577836800` as `real` number is in scientific notation by default: `1.5778368e+09`. The cast to `json` preserves that. Voilá.

Cast all floating-point input to `numeric` before you stuff it into an array.

**Or** use `jsonb` instead of `json`. `jsonb` casts numeric data to the type  `numeric` to store them as such internally. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-KEYS-ELEMENTS)

> One semantically-insignificant detail worth noting is that in `jsonb`, numbers will be printed according to the behavior of the underlying `numeric` type. In practice this means that numbers entered with **`E`** notation will be printed without it ...